# Physical Process Tree of MapReduce Jobs in Hadoop (over the cluster nodes)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata

I read a lot of references, book chapters & articles, but I'm still trying to glue everything together :
I fairly understand the MapReduce Logical chain, but I specifically would like to know what specific processes are launched on which physical node over time.

I guess mappers are executed "on site" on datanode machines, but what about the other processes, specifically reducers, who need to access data over multiple datanodes ?

Also, if I get it well, the map and reduce written programs are launched on the master node where the command is executed, and result in launching new threads on new JVMs all over the cluster, is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to visit http://bytepadding.com/map-reduce/

to give you an overview.

1. MapReduce client can be launched locally or on a dataNode(oozie launcher).
2. Based on the inputFormat the file location is fetched from namenode by the MapreduceDriver(Application Master)
3. Based on file split policy, mappers are launched and the process tries to spawn mappers as close as possible to individual file blocks.
4. Mappers are spawned on dataNodes.
5. After Mappers have finshed, reducer are launched on DataNodes and data from mappers are copied on these specific machines.